# Deployment order of war's in jboss5

Tags: deployment, jboss, war, web-deployment, jboss5.x

Imagine that I have 2 web applications in jboss5 (as a 2 .war files):

b1.war
a1.war

By default those wars are deployed in alphabetical order (a1 then b1).
If in my architecture a1 needs to be deployed AFTER b1 -> how can I accomplish this?

Is there some xml file (like web.xml) where I could declare the specific order of deployment?
I searched on internet for this but I could not get any useful info.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try sorting the order using application.xml (https://community.jboss.org/thread/233102)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Jboss5.x, you can achieve this by creating different directories under deploy folder.

For example:
create two folders, "a" and "b"

put the war/ear/sar files in folder "a" which needs to be deployed first, the later folder "b" can be used for deploying war/ear/sar which needs to be deployed after the contents of folder "a" is deployed on Jboss.

**JBoss lists the contents in alphabetical order of folders under "/deploy"** and then proceeds with deployment.